# Bluetooth function lost and Wifi only on 5GHz band on Windows 11 Asus Laptop with Realtek 8821CE network adapter

Tags: wireless-networking, bluetooth, windows-11

Last week I bought a new Asus Laptop running on Windows 11 (see detailed configuration below). This laptop comes with a Wifi and Bluetooth functionalities. Everything worked fine until Friday, when **the Bluetooth icon decided not to show up in windows taskbar** after startup.

I saw that this is somewhat of a common error and followed [Microsoft's suggested fixes](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/fix-bluetooth-problems-in-windows-723e092f-03fa-858b-5c80-131ec3fba75c#:%7E:text=see%20more%20info.-,Run%20the%20Bluetooth%20troubleshooter,troubleshooter%20and%20follow%20the%20instructions.).  I tried updating the driver and running the troubleshooter to no avail. Ultimately, I followed the instruction of uninstalling the Bluetooth adapter from the Device manager.

This is where things started to go south: after reboot, **Windows does not detect my Bluetooth adapter anymore**. I tried:

1. Starting "Bluetooth Support Service" in the "service.msc" tool;
2. Reinstalling new drivers from Asus website
3. Reverting back to factory settings (twice)

All this gave no result. I still do not have Bluetooth capability and the Bluetooth adapter remains absent from the "Device manager" (even though I am showing hidden devices and scanned for hardware change).

But there is more.

While trying to connect my laptop to my old Wifi router (which only emits in the 2.4GHz band), I discovered that **my laptop can only see Wifi networks that emit on the 5GHz band**. This is strange because my integrated network adapter, a [Realtek 8821CE](https://www.realtek.com/en/products/communications-network-ics/item/rtl8821ce?utm_source=everythingRF) is supposed to detect both 2.4GHz and 5GHz bands.

According to the manufacturer's website, it seems that the Realtek 8821CE is also the chip that offers the Bluetooth capability. I therefore suspect that this chip is somehow malfunctioning and causes the 2 problems that I observed: failure of Bluetooth and Wifi limited to 5GHz band.

**In the end, could you tell me whether my problems are caused by a software issue that I can solve, or is my network adapter faulty and I should return the laptop?**

**Additional info:**

*Device specs:*

- Processor    Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1065G7 CPU @ 1.30GHz   1.50 GHz
- Installed RAM    8,00 GB (7,74 GB usable)
- ID   C4EBFA60-6B20-47E6-8032-ACE9FE43F8EE
- Product ID   00342-21980-93827-AAOEM
- System type  64-bit operating system, x64-based processor

*Windows specs:*

- Edition  Windows 11 Home
- Version  21H2
- Installed on ‎23/‎07/‎2022
- OS build 22000.832
- Experience   Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22000.832.0

View of the device manager before I uninstalled the Bluetooth adapter:

[image]

View of the device manager now (with "show hidden devices" enabled):

[image]

Comment: Can you enable hidden devices and repost your second device manager screenshot?

Comment: WiFi is working and Bluetooth is not. It could be the wireless card or a daughter card.  Given your actions and tests, yes, get the machine serviced or replaced.

Comment: @Ramhound: I re-uploaded the last image, making sure the "show hidden devices" is enabled.

Comment: If a reinstall, or driver install, doesn't fix this, because it's a new computer the best thing to do is to replace the computer. Don't let this turn you away from a given brand. Computer failure rates over the life of a computer are always U shaped. There are more failures in brand new computers, and then as the computers age the failure rates go down and then start tracking upwards again.

Comment: Is this a new or "new" computer you purchased used?  10th generation intel processor seems to suggest it's used.

Comment: The computer is a brand new one I purchased last Monday. Do you mean there is something wrong with this model?

Comment: It does appear to be a hardware issue.

Answer (score 0):

Asus ZenBook 425EA here. The Bluetooth just disappeared suddenly one day, while I was using it.

What worked for me was:

- Open Device Manager
- Under Universal Serial Bus Controllers, there was one device with a yellow warning icon, which had "failed to report" what it was
- I went to that device's properties, Disabled it, and then Enabled it again

When I did that, the Bluetooth immediately came back online.

Original answer here: https://superuser.com/a/1739038/52910